# Where can I find the generated binaries when building MediaPipe from source?

Tags: bazel, mediapipe

I'm trying to build MediaPipe 0.8.5 from source on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS with Google Colab. Here are the detailed steps I tried

```
!git clone https://github.com/google/mediapipe.git
%cd mediapipe
!git checkout tags/v0.8.5
!bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1
```

The build command appeared to execute successfully, as indicated by the output logging.

[image]

However, I noticed that the 'bazel-bin' directory is empty. Where can I find the generated binaries?

I also tried

```
!bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_cpu
```

> Analyzing: target
> //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_c\ pu (1
> packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching @rules_cc; fetching
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ ERROR: An error occurred
> during the fetch of repository 'rules_cc':    Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl",
> line 111, column 45, in _http_archive_impl        download_info =
> ctx.download_and_extract( Error in download_and_extract:
> java.io.IOException: Error extracting
> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924/master.zip
> to
> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924:
> Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here
> are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main". Analyzing:
> target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_c
> pu (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ ERROR: While resolving
> toolchains for target
> //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_cpu:
> com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.RepositoryFetchException: no
> such package '@rules_cc//cc': java.io.IOException: Error extracting
> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924/master.zip
> to
> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924:
> Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here
> are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main". Analyzing:
> target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_c
> pu (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ ERROR: Analysis of target
> '//mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_cpu'
> failed; build aborted:
> com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.RepositoryFetchException: no
> such package '@rules_cc//cc': java.io.IOException: Error extracting
> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924/master.zip
> to
> /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/84712663721631c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924:
> Prefix "rules_cc-master" was given, but not found in the archive. Here
> are possible prefixes for this archive: "rules_cc-main". Analyzing:
> target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_c
> pu (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ INFO: Elapsed time:
> 1.433s Analyzing: target //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_c\ pu (1
> packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ INFO: 0 processes.
> Analyzing: target
> //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_c\ pu (1
> packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ FAILED: Build did NOT
> complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 0 targets conf\ igured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216\ FAILED: Build did NOT
> complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 0 targets conf\ igured)
> currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
> Fetching ...les_cc; Extracting /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/847126637216
> 31c6211d09ab74d72aa8/external/rules_cc/temp9801135472723615924/master.zip

Comment: Why not use a newer version?

Comment: @BenjaminPeterson Because a MediaPipe [tutorial](https://youtu.be/doDUihpj6ro?t=268) uses MediaPipe 0.8.5 and the latest version doesn't support `mediapipe.solutions.holistic.FACE_CONNECTIONS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide any target for Bazel to build, and therefore it successfully built nothing. Try building an example: `bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 //mediapipe/examples/desktop/face_detection:face_detection_cpu`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and I got `ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'rules_cc'`. I also updated my OP.

Comment: It seems 0.8.5 failed to pin a dependency and now that dependency has changed in an incompatible way.